# If I omit "await" in an async call, will the operation still complete?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

This is about Javascript and latest Node.JS.

I have an asynchronous operation (HTTP call via the Axios library in this particular case, but the question is in general). I *don't care* what the result of that operation is. If it succeeds - nice. If it fails - whatever. But I know it might take a while to complete and I cannot wait that long. So I want to "fire and forget".

Now, the first idea is simply to remove the `await` from the call. I'll get a `Promise` that I promptly forget about and the operation will complete on its own terms. I think this should work, but... feels kinda wrong. I can't put my finger on it, but it bugs me.

Is this safe, or should I better still hold on to the `Promise` and check its results in a timer or something, even though I won't do anything with them?

Comment: No, you don't have to hold on to the Promise. Just ignore it. However, if the HTTP request fails, you will get a rejected promise, and that will trigger an exception if you did not `catch` that.

Comment: There's no penalty in awaiting. `await` is non-blocking except for immediately dependent code. Therefore you can await (or `.then()`) with impunity, even if you do nothing with the resulting data/error.

Comment: That's just it. There are things I need to do immediately afterwards that cannot wait. At least not as long as the particular asynchronous operation will take.

Comment: Then do the immediate things without awaiting.

Comment: Yup. That's what this question was about - can I skip awaiting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not interested in the notification of a successful HTTP request, you still have to take into account what happens when the HTTP request fails for some reason (server not responding, no internet connection, ...).

You don't need to retain a promise object, and you don't even need `async`, but you should at the very least deal with a promise rejection, as otherwise you will get an "unhandled promise rejection" exception.

So do:

```
fetch(url).catch(err => { /* deal with error */ });
```

If you don't care about the error either (I doubt that), then you can just do:

```
fetch(url).catch(Boolean);
```

This way you are left with a promise that will never reject. So you can ignore it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what does putting the `Boolean` interface into catch (where it expects a function that takes an error) exactly do here?

Comment: It takes the error message and returns a boolean value for it, which will be `true`. We don't care about this, as we only want `catch` to absorb the error, so any function could do. It would also work with `.catch(Number)`, `.catch(String)`, `.catch(Object)`, .... but resolving the promise with `true` is more "neutral"... Alternatively, `.catch(() => null)`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that we can use interfaces themselves instead of functions. Thank you!

Comment: No, it is not an interface (that is a TypeScript thing, not JavaScript). `Number`, `Boolean`, `String`, `Object` are all native **functions**. You can do `Number("123")` and `Boolean("123")`.

Answer (score 2):

In your function, everything you wrote after the `await` statement will be put into a queue to execute after the asynchronous process is completed. So that way node js keep the event loop free for run any other codes.

I mean,

```
async function getName() {
  const name = await db.getName();
  console.log(name); // <--- this will put into a queue to execute after above line completed 
}
```

So technically if you don't want wait to execute `console.log(name)` until the above line finish, you can just remove the `await` keyword

```
function getName() {
  db.getName(); // <-- you don't even need to store it to a variable
  console.log(name);
}
```

Above function is 100% synchronous. But, you have to catch the error, otherwise if it fails js throws unhandle promise rejection error. So you can easily do like below,

```
function getName() {
  db.getName().catch(err => undefined); // <-- you don't even need to store it to a variable
  console.log(name);   
}
```

Comment: Ah sorry. I forgot to remove `async` keyword

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding well, *then* and *catch* are your best options:

```
myPromise
   .then(whatever => /* do whatever non-blocking operation you want */)
   .catch(error => /* deal with error if any */);

// you code here is not blocked by the promise
```